# Using startswith() to detect blank input

Tags: python, conditional-statements, is-empty

```py
while True:
    familar_name = input('Enter your name: ')

    if familar_name.startswith(""):
        print('Please enter a valid name')
    elif familar_name.isalpha():
        print('Hello', familar_name)
        break
```

I'm trying to detect a blank input. `elif` statement never met even when entering an alphabetical input.

Comment: Your `elif` statement should be `elif familiar_name.isalpha():` - you need the parentheses to call the `isalpha` method.

Comment: You might want to try `if not familar_name.strip(): print('Please enter a valid name')` as an empty string is "falsey"

Answer (score 4):

A string always starts with an empty string, this condition is True. That's why your elif statement doesn't work:

```py
a = "hi"
if a.startswith(""):
    print('yes')
```

output:

```
yes
```

In order to check the blank input, you can just check for truthiness of the  `familar_name` like :

```py
name = input('enter your name')
if name:
    ...
```

The above if statement's body will execute if the string is not blank. But this will fail if user passes whitespaces. So maybe you need to use `.strip()` before that checking.

Also don't forget to call `.isalpha` method --> `.isalpha()`

Answer (score 1):

use `" "` instead of `""`

```
while True:

    familar_name = input('enter your name') 

    if familar_name.startswith(" "): # you have to have a space here.
       print('Please enter a valid name')
    elif familar_name.isalpha():
       print('Hello', familar_name)
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

check for any whitespace (not just blank space) with lstrip(): this will catch more cases.

```
while True:

    familar_name = input('enter your name') 

    if familar_name.lstrip() != familiar_name:
        print('Please enter a valid name')
    elif familar_name.isalpha:
        print('Hello', familar_name)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for blank input something like this:

```
while True:
  familar_name = input('enter your name: ') 
  if not len(familar_name):
    print('Please enter a valid name')
  elif familar_name.isalpha():
    print('Hello', familar_name)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a string is empty or not.

```py
string = 'Example'

# Way 1

if not string:
    print('String is empty')

if string:
    print('String is not empty')

# Way 2

if string == '':
    print('String is empty')

if string != '':
    print('String is not empty')

# Way 3

if len(string) == 0:
    print('String is empty')

if len(string) != 0:
    print('String is not empty')
```